# Is there a cross-axis counterpart to the "flex-grow" property (or "flex"), which affects only the main-axis?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, terminology

In Flexbox there are concepts of "main-axis" and "cross-axis". Generally on a browser the "main-axis" would be horizontal, presumably because desktop and laptop screens are usually in landscape orientation, whereas in React Native, the "main-axis" is generally vertical since it's primarily for phones, which are most often in portrait orientation. Whichever of these is the "main-axis", the other is then known as the "cross-axis".

It seems that also in Flexbox many properties that affect the main-axis have a counterpart with a different name that affects the cross-axis.

There is a property called `flex-grow` and another just called `flex` that can do the job of `flex-grow` and some others at once.

What I'm unclear on is whether this `flex-grow` is one of the properties that has a counterpart, or if it's an exception. The same goes for the `flex` property.

One reason I ask is that I often read that when trying to get your layout right that you might need to set `flex` to `1` for your element and all of its counter/parent elements. But what about where places in your layout need to achieve the same goal, but in the cross-axis?

Comment: Is this where `display: grid` comes in?

Comment: generally, nested flex containers with alternating row and column orientation, using flex grow on the nested containers ( as they are also flex items ) accomplishes this, assuming the outside container of all of this has some defined size, i.e. the cross-axis fills the parent container

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `flex-grow` (and the shorthand `flex`) property always affect the *main axis*, has **no** counterpart, and sets how to distribute the free space horizontally for *flex row direction* and vertically for *flex column direction*.

In comparison, for example the `justify-content` property affects the *main axis*, has a counterpart, the `align-items` which affect the *cross axis*, where both sets the alignment of the flex items.

What can be confusing here though, is that based on the *flow direction* they affect either the flex items horizontally or vertically.

---

Note, the *main* and *cross axis* has nothing to do with whether the screen is wide or tall.

It has to do with the *flow direction*, so for a *flex row direction*, which is the default, the *main axis* is horizontal and the *cross axis* is vertical, and for a *flex column direction*, the *main axis* is vertical and the *cross axis* is horizontal.

A really good article is [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), which explains this more thoroughly.

Comment: About your note, that's why I said "generally". I thought about it and it's more about web vs React Native but couldn't remember where I knew it from at the time. Was I right or wrong about the necessity to specify flex for all the parents as well as the element to get it to work? I'll see if I can find where I got that from too ...

Comment: @hippietrail You set the `flex` property on the _flex item_, which has a parent with `display: flex`, the _flex container_, and for every item which need something else than the default `flex: 0 1 auto`

Comment: And if some of the parents are using `flex-direction: row` and others are using `flex-direction: column` that doesn't matter? (I didn't know those terms when I posted the question.)

Comment: @hippietrail No, that won't matter, and it will will always affect the _main axis_, which again, is either horizontal or vertical based on the _flex direction_

Comment: Hmm so in the case that an element and its parent have opposite `flex-direction` you can't actually set the `flex-grow` for each parent meaningfully because it only applies to the main-axis, and the parent has it set for a different main axis. Am I still just not getting it?

Comment: @hippietrail That is correct that it only apply on the _main axis_, though you set `flex-grow` on the _flex child_, not _flex parent_. This demo hopefully show that: https://jsfiddle.net/sy03ge9p/3/

Comment: I thought though to get the `flex-grow` of the child to work that you often have to set if for its parents and all ancestors. Maybe this is something that's different in React Native or I read incorrect tips? I'm using React Native where you build the whole UI with nested flexboxes - maybe that much nesting is a lot rarer in web React?

Comment: @hippietrail I have less knowledge in React's different solutions and more with Flexbox in general, though frameworks often repeat both _parent_ and _child_ properties on all items in case of them being nested to make sure it work at all levels, which of course can create some confusion of what is what when one dive into a specific technology.

Comment: Ah I now think a new question asking specifically about React Native is in order. At least in this regard it's not really a framework, it just uses it's own elements instead of HTML elements and flex is the primary layout method just with `flex-direction` defaulting to `column` rather than `row`. I just learned that flex properties are not hierarchical though so `flex-grow` is just about that container and its immediate children. But the advice to set `flex-grow:1` on all ancestor nodes up the chain looks like something hierarchical is being dealt with. A source of confusion I'd say.

Answer (score 7):

If you'd like to modify a flex item in the cross-axis (vertically by default, or horizontally if the flex container has `flex-direction: column;` set) then consider using the `align-self` property. To make a flex item "grow" in the cross axis direction, `align-self: stretch;` on that item should work. This is only useful if the container already has `align-items` set to something like `center`.

Note that this is *similar* to "flex-grow" in the cross axis, but definitely not the same thing. See the complete guide for more details: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: tan;
  align-items: center;
}

.small-stretched-item {
  background-color: green;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.tall-item {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
 }
 
 .small-unstretched-item {
   background-color: pink;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="small-stretched-item">Small, stretched item</span>
  <div class="tall-item">Tall item</div>
  <span class="small-unstretched-item">Small, unstretched item</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This can then for example be combined with `margin-top: 10%` and `margin-bottom: 10%` to achieve a height of 80%. However this seems to be somewhat broken if you target multiple elements of different height. Unfortunately I have no idea why. But for one flex container it should be fine